# Snort rule to detect http flood

Tags: security, snort, flooding

Is it possible to use Snort to detect valid repetitive HTTP GET requests?
 eg. a client machine is sending HTTP requests to flood a server.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but your question is a little confusing, you want to detect "valid" HTTP GET requests, as opposed to "invalid" HTTP GET requests? Do you have criteria for what makes the get requests "valid" (i.e. requiring something in the http header)? Snort would would typically be used to detect "invalid" requests and block them. Why would you want to detect valid get requests? Please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do here.

Comment: For example; Someone is sending repetitive HTTP GET aiming to flood a Web Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fyi, it would be much more likely (and a much easier/more common attack) that your web server would get syn flooded before an "HTTP GET flood", so you would likely want to prevent this type of attack first.

Anyway, you can accomplish this with the [detection_filter](http://manual.snort.org/node538.html) option and a simple content match.  Let's say your web server's IP address is 192.168.1.5 and it is going over port 80 only, an example rule would be as follows:

```
alert tcp any any -> 192.168.1.5 80 (msg:"GET Request flood attempt"; \
flow:to_server,established; content:"GET"; nocase; http_method; \
detection_filter:track by_src, count 30, seconds 30; metadata: service http;)
```

This rule will fire on every GET request from a single IP address to 192.168.1.5 during one sampling period of 30 seconds, after the first 30 GET requests.

Example:

- 1.2.3.4 sends a GET request to 192.168.1.5, the 30 second counter will start and the count will be 1.
- 1.2.3.4 sends 29 more GET requests in 10 seconds, no alerts will be generated. The counter is at 30 and it has been 10 second.
- For the next 20 seconds any GET request from 1.2.3.4 to 192.168.1.5 will generate an alert.